# Using copy algorithm to copy from vector to set

Tags: c++, stl

As a purely learning experience I want to be able to use the `copy` algorithm to copy from a vector to a set.  This is what I am trying to do:

```
vector<int> myVector = {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    
// set<int> mySet(myVector.begin(), myVector.end());
// This works, no issues
    
set<int> mySet;
copy(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), some_inserter_that_will_work(mySet));
```

Somewhere on the web it was suggested that the `inserter` function would work but it is giving me the following compile error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘inserter(std::set&)’

Comment: [`std::insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator)?

Comment: The error says you're using `inserter` wrong. It has two parameters.

Comment: Might be relevant here. You are aware that you can initialize a set directly from the vector, right? Like this: `std::set<int> set(vec.begin(), vec.end());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`std::inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) in this way, indicating the insertion position as second argument:

```
copy(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), inserter(mySet, mySet.end()));
```